# Google safe browsing API 403 error: The request is missing a valid API key

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-cloud-platform, safe-browsing, safe-browsing-api

My ajax code is as follows:

```
    $("#my_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 

    var api_url = "https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?"
    var key = 'A..............................s'
    api_url += key

    console.log(api_url);

    var payload = 
    {
        "client":{
            "clientId": "2815.........................apps.googleusercontent.com",
            "clientVersion": "1.0.0",
        },
        "threatInfo": {
            "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
            "platformTypes":    ["WINDOWS"],
            "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
            "threatEntries": [
              {"url": "http://www.pitt.edu/"},
              {"url": "http://www.exchange.pitt.edu/"}
            ]
          }
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: api_url,
        contentType: "applicaiton/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
    success:function (data) {
        console.log("ok");
         console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(status){
        console.log("fail");
        console.log(status);
    }
    });
```

I have the API enabled for my project
[API image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njK0N.png)

And I created credentials for a api key. I've tried enabling Oath 2.0 credentials in order to get my client id.

[Credentials image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbLIn.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are adding the API key as an unnamed parameter.

Change this line:

```
api_url += key
```

To:

```
api_url += "key="
api_url += key
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not passing the required query string parameter here `key`. You can add it like:

```
api_url += `key=${key}`;
```